# Python Regex exclude matches with letters after /

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have 3 strings as follows:

/foo

/foo/

/foo/bar

If the strings match the first 2 patters I want to return True

If the string has anything after the second forward slash I want to return False

My regex is

```
re.match(r"^/[a-z]+/?", string)
```

I can't work out how to exclude the third pattern. Please help. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
^\/[^\/]*\/?$
```

Explanation:

- `^`: start of word
- `\/`: forward slash at beginning
- `[^\/]*` any number of non-forward-slash characters. If you want this to just be letters you can make it `[a-x]*`
- `\/?` optional forward slash
- `$` end of word - no more characters

You can try it out with your examples [here](https://regex101.com/r/flI7Lw/1), and see sample code [here](https://regex101.com/r/flI7Lw/1/codegen?language=python).

Comment: amazing!! Thank you so much. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$` to denote the end of a string:

```
^/[a-z]+/?$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/v12sWr/1